# Accessing an FTP share via UNC path?

Tags: firewall, ftp, azure, unc

I have an FTP share configured on a server that I can access successfully using `ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx/`.

One of my tools (Release Management) requires a UNC path for access:

[image]

Is there any way that I can use UNC pathing to access a folder on a remote machine (Azure VM) over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use UNC paths to refer to locations on FTP. UNC paths imply SMB/local Windows paths.

An alternative would be to mount a FTP site as a local drive, and then pass that local path to your tool. See e.g. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows

Answer (score 0):

What you think of for UNC paths `\\server\share` are typically for SMB/CIFS aka "Windows file shares", not FTP.

You can use a free Samba server to host the files you need and they'll be accessible by a UNC path:

Some links for you:

https://www.samba.org

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch01.html

Here is Samba file server setup for Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html